# Apps Development in Napa Tool

Tags: office-365, 2013, office-365-develop-tool

Which type of apps from following can be developed using Napa Tool in Office 365?

1) SharePoint Hosted App

2) Provider Hosted App

3) Auto Hosted App

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SharePoint Hosted App only. But you can also build Office App in Napa.

Comment: Thank You. I was not sure about this but i was thinking that in Napa we can develop SP Hosted App..